# Why elastic fuzzy search param "fuzziness" is not working?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

This is my search query：

```js
    query = {
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "medicine_name": {
        "query": "query",
        "fuzziness": 1,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want ES to return a `medicine_name` that's `edit_distance` value between query and it was smaller than 1,
but ES returns all `medicine_name`'s sorted by `edit_distance`.

So my question is what is going wrong?

Comment: Can you add sample medicine_name values in your question? Your medicine_name has "query" string in it?

Comment: when "fuzziness"= 1, "query"="Amoxicillin", es will return Amoxicillin  , Amox ,Azlocillin

Comment: Fuzziness works fine for me (tried for text field). Is the mapping or analyzer for medicine_name special? Or do you have an additional filter subquery or anything like that. Could it be that you posted just a part of the whole query?

Comment: @phybrain can you provide your index mapping? Because it works fine for me with the default mapping. I am assuming that you're using an analyzer for the "medicine_name" field (possibly NGram or edge NGram).